# Class 'Mage' not found in /usr/share/php/SOAP/WSDL.php on line 214

Tags: magento

I am receiving this error...
Class 'Mage' not found in /usr/share/php/SOAP/WSDL.php on line 214
...and have tracked it down to the line

```
require_once('Zend/Log.php');
```

Can any one advise me on how to debug this so I can find out where the class causing this error is as I am at a loss.

Comment: The class Mage is in [magento doc root]/app/Mage.php. Are you running script from some other location or external script ?

Comment: @daktau Can you mention the code which you are using in the question.It  will be helpfull for others to answer.